# Lopsided percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to make a table in Excel where I have two different sets of data totaling different amounts representing market share in two different markets (totals=550,000 tons and 700,000 tons) and I need to make these relative terms so that I can have a percent of the combined total of the two markets (550,000+700,000=1,250,000) where 550,000 is considered a 50% of the market in market A and 700,000 is considered a 50% share in market B and then as I adjust the values within each market, the % of the market share changes accordingly i.e.

MARKET A

Ohio 300,000
Idaho 100,000
Cali 150,000
A Total 550,000
Combined Total: 1,250,000
Market share 50%

MARKET B

DC 300,000,
Tex 300,000
NY 100,000
B Total 700,000
Combined Total: 1,250,000
Market share 50%

Then I want to be able to adjust the values within the table i.e. changing Ohio to 400,000 and having the combined total and market % of Market A (which includes Ohio) increase while the market % of market B decreases a proportionate amount so that the total is always 100%

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a scaling factor to everything in market A.  Multiply them all by $\frac {700,000}{550,000}$  Use the scaled market A values and the real market B values to assess market share.  A will have $50\%$ of the market share as requested.  If you put these scaling factors in a column and the scaled values in the next column, when Ohio goes from $300,000$ to $400,000$ the scaled value will go from $381,818$ to $509,091$ and the market share of A will increase from $50\%$ to $54.1\%$.

Comment: Thanks, Ross.  Is there any way for me to make the Market values i.e. 700,000 and 550,000 dynamic without making the equations circularly referencing equations?

Comment: @David:  I am not understanding the purpose of this.  You can certainly change the scaling to keep A and B at 50%.  Just scale all the A's by $\frac BA$  You can then allocate the 50% withing groups A and B using the scaled values.  It's not circular.